# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'hist'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am trying to plot a histogram of SLA operations but the code returns the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'hist'.

This is the code:

```
gsheet = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JghWt9yjnkV7leM-NKvvTEPXUvep18y7G9MlbMxi7-g/edit#gid=1757725935')
gsquad = gsheet.worksheet('bd_movpay')
data = gsquad.get_all_values()
headers = data.pop(0)

df_squad = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
df_squad.head()

data.hist(column = 'sla_chat', bins = 10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The variable 'data' is of the type list. Instead use ``` df.hist``` instead of ``` data.hist```

Comment: List has no method name hist

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to generate the plot from the list and not from the dataframe. Try this:

```py
df_squad.hist(column = 'sla_chat', bins = 10)
```